# MVC - Missing Property Data in Details, Edit, and Delete Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to programming and having some trouble with a MVC 5 project. Specifically, within the auto-generated views details, edit and delete. Data is missing for fields which pull data from another model/table.

A have a table with form data known as "Shoutouts." Include is the user's first and last name, and a class known as "Level" which contains a weighted value with a name and an Id.

I was able to work around this by discovering how to use `.Inlcude()` in the ActionResult for the Index.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder) 
{
        var allShoutouts = db.Shoutouts
            .Include(s => s.User)
            .Include(s => s.Level);
        return View(allShoutouts);
}
```

But I don't understand how to do it in the other views as well since they need the ShoutoutId to passed through the return.

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    ShoutoutFormViewModel SFVM = new ShoutoutFormViewModel();
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Shoutout shoutout = db.Shoutouts.Find(id);

    if (shoutout == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(shoutout);
}

public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Shoutout shoutout = db.Shoutouts.Find(id);
    if (shoutout == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(shoutout);
}

public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Shoutout shoutout = db.Shoutouts.Find(id);

    if (shoutout == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(shoutout);
}
```

[Here's what the page looks like for delete as an example of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBBk4.png)

I couldn't find any similar questions on Stack Overflow or Google so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should probably go back and read about how data gets passed to the view.  specifically what is a ViewModel.

Comment: your question is not clear, can you describe your goal?

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros The goal was to get data from two different tables to display in an index of another. When a user fills out a form for a "shoutout", that pulls information from the two tables and is saved into a main one known as "Shoutouts". However, I was having issues where that data was not displaying within the edit, delete, and details view from the two other tables. Tim's suggested worked though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have the id:

```
var shoutout = db.Shoutouts
        .Include(s => s.User)
        .Include(s => s.Level)
        .Single(s => s.Id == id);
    return View(allShoutouts);
```